# I wanted to use elementary-dark-mono icons on my panel

Tags: icons

I have downloaded Faenza-Fresh icon theme. This theme inherits faenza cupertino. Faenza cupertino, in the other hand, inherit faenza.

So, my panel icons become dark and very hard to see because my panel is dark in color. I really love elementary-dark-mono icons on my panel. How do I change the `.theme` in order for this Faenza-Fresh icon theme uses elementary-dark-mono icons **ONLY** on my panel?

Here is the `.theme` file for Faenza Fresh:

```
Icon Theme]
Name=Faenza-Fresh
Inherits=Faenza-Cupertino,elementary-mono-dark
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you elementary-dark-mono to inherit Faenza-Fresh and choose elementary-dark-mono as your icon theme. Here is my ubuntu-mono inheriting Faenza-Mint and Faenza-Cupertino. In order to use the icons system wise be sure to store it in `/usr/share/icons`. You may need to remove ubuntu-mono places icons as well with `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-*/places/*`

[image]